# Outlook Add-In Category Flag Status (Deprecated flagicon)

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to add a category color to my categories to make it more clear to the end-user.
The problem is, it seems that mailItem.FlagIcon is deprecated and there is no replacement for it.
I know I can still use the FlagIcon, but deprecated means, old, not used anymore, and I do not want a new 2016 application having a dependency on a deprecated and possibly removed function.

To be clear, see the image of what I am talking about.

[image: Deprecated function]

I currently use :
`Outlook.MailItem.FlagIcon = Outlook.OlFlagIcon.olRedFlagIcon`

I also use :
`Outlook.MailItem.FlagIcon = Outlook.OlFlagIcon.olYellowFlagIcon`

The red one works, the orange does not, as said above, I do not want to be dependant on these functions anymore, but there seems no way of accomplishing this without using these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that you shouldn't set FlagIcon.  However, you cannot directly assign a color the way you are thinking.  All you can do is add the category you want to MailItem.Categories; the color is pre-assigned and managed in the Master Category List.  So if you want to change the color for the category you must get the relevant Category object from the Store.Categories collection (each Store has a different MCL), and set Category.Color to the value you want.  This will update ALL existing categories in ALL items to display the newly assigned color.

Comment: Its too bad that they have deprecated this feature, my collegues are really used to this feature, as am I. Atleast we have a way to get it working again now :) cheers!

Comment: It was deprecated starting with Outlook 2007 I believe

Comment: unfortunatly this is a bad work around for us, I tried this, but after testing it (works on all clients) we found out that we cannot programmicly add all the categories with coloring to the Master Category List, and have to do this by hand, thats a bit much for thousands of clients :P

Comment: But you absolutely can do that! You of course have to run the operation individually and may have to run it repeatedly to ensure categories haven't been removed or changed colors. Is that the challenge?

Comment: I guess the challenge can become bigger when we decide to go server side, currently we run it clientside which is actually doing multiple times the same work, and this results in duplicates.
We want to do it serverside so we tackle this problem + we do not have any problems with our standard outlook rulings (if an email comes from a certain email adres, it gets filtered server side into a certain folder.) which is kind a problem since my program does not understand that (yet).

Comment: What's the application architecture for your server-side mail processing? An Exchange transport agent? Just curious

Comment: We do not have anything on the server-side but we have been looking into this, for example going to an Exchange transport agent.